# "an existing" vs "existing"?

Tags: word-choice

I have just asked a question on a forum. It has the words "how to clone an existing target?" and I have realized that probably I should not have `an` included there.

What is the right way of saying: `an existing target` or just `existing target`?

Thanks.

Comment: As per the context, a singular countable noun need a determiner before it. '*I need pen' is ungrammatical. It should be "I need a/the/your pen", as per the context.

Answer (score 1):

"How to clone an existing target?" sounds natural to me. However, I don't know anything about the context so I can't say for sure that the adjective used in the question is apt.